# python - how to get socket connection state?

Tags: python, sockets

**Hi!**

I'm beginer in python, and i want to ask here.
I have code. When I click the button (btn_connect), socket connects to the tv (function self.connection()). Is there way to check socket connection and get connected or disconnected? I want write it to the text field, like "Status: Connected"

**Here is my code:**

```
import fcntl, socket, struct
import base64
import time, datetime
import netifaces
from Tkinter import *

def getMyMac1(ifname):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    info = fcntl.ioctl(s.fileno(), 0x8927,  struct.pack('256s', ifname[:15]))
    return '-'.join(['%02x' % ord(char) for char in info[18:24]])


myip = netifaces.ifaddresses(netifaces.gateways()['default'][netifaces.AF_INET][1])[netifaces.AF_INET][0]['addr']
mymac = getMyMac1(netifaces.gateways()['default'][netifaces.AF_INET][1])
appstring = "Pepin's Samsung TV Remote"
remotename = "Pepin's Samsung TV Remote"

def sendKey(skey, dataSock, appstring):
 messagepart3 = chr(0x00) + chr(0x00) + chr(0x00) + chr(len(
base64.b64encode(skey))) + chr(0x00) + base64.b64encode(skey);
 part3 = chr(0x00) + chr(len(appstring)) + chr(0x00) \
+ appstring + chr(len(messagepart3)) + chr(0x00) + messagepart3
 dataSock.send(part3);

root = Tk()
root.title("Pepin's Samsung TV Remote")
root.geometry("391x595")

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
ipencoded = base64.b64encode(myip)
macencoded = base64.b64encode(mymac)

messagepart1 = chr(0x64) + chr(0x00) + chr(len(ipencoded)) \
+ chr(0x00) + ipencoded + chr(len(macencoded)) + chr(0x00) \
+ macencoded + chr(len(base64.b64encode(remotename))) + chr(0x00) \
+ base64.b64encode(remotename)
part1 = chr(0x00) + chr(len(appstring)) + chr(0x00) + appstring \
+ chr(len(messagepart1)) + chr(0x00) + messagepart1
messagepart2 = chr(0xc8) + chr(0x00)
part2 = chr(0x00) + chr(len(appstring)) + chr(0x00) + appstring \
+ chr(len(messagepart2)) + chr(0x00) + messagepart2

class Application():
    """Pepin's Samsung TV Remote"""

    def __init__(self, master):

        self.master = master
        self.create_widgets()

    def connection(self):

        sock.connect((self.entry_tvip.get(), 55000))
        sock.send(part1)
        sock.send(part2)

        self.tvappstring = app.entry_tvappstring.get()

    def create_widgets(self):

        label_tvip = Label(self.master, text="TV IP:")
        label_tvip.grid(row=3, column=3, columnspan=1, padx=(15,0), ipady=8)

        self.entry_tvip = Entry(self.master, width=16)
        self.entry_tvip.grid(row=3, column=4, columnspan=3, ipady=8)

        label_tvappstring = Label(self.master, text="TV MODEL (Tv App String)")
        label_tvappstring.grid(row=4, column=3, columnspan=4, padx=(15,0), ipady=8, sticky=W)

        self.entry_tvappstring = Entry(self.master, width=22)
        self.entry_tvappstring.grid(row=5, column=3, columnspan=4, padx=(15,0), ipady=8)
        self.entry_tvappstring.insert(0, "UE55C8000")

        btn_connect = Button(self.master, text = "CONNECT TO TV", width=19, height=2, command = lambda: self.connection()) 
            btn_connect.grid(row=6, column=3, columnspan=5, padx=(15,0))     

app = Application(root)
root.mainloop()

sock.close()
```

**Please help me.
Thank you!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Connected socket:**

Your stream connected socket blocks and recv() returns "" when closed on other end. So there is your status.

**UDP:**

The datagram UDP socket is broadcast so state is a bit nebulous, certainly compared to a connected one.

Your tv gadgetry surely has documentation on the
flow for UDP right? Such as a sendto() status request or some equivalent concept.

http://www.binarytides.com/programming-udp-sockets-in-python/

Comment: thanks, I try it at morning. I have midnight right now.

Comment: The UDP socket is being used just to discover the Ethernet MAC address, so only the TCP connection is a problem in this example.

Comment: Can you point me to some url on how you talk to this `sock` and what status label you are referring to

Comment: Socket is connecting to TVs server application on port 55000. On this port socket sendings keys to TV. Is TV remote applications.